# How do I generate the input /output columns dynamically in SSIS script component (transformation) using BIML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, biml, ssis-2014

How do I dynamically generate script component(transformation) input and output columns using BIML?

I have created [microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com's 2015-02 sample](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2015/02/creating-biml-script-component.html?m=1)

The problem with that approach is the input and output columns for script component are hard coded.

I  have 1000 files. For each file, the input and output columns in the component vary.Can anybody help me on that?

Thanks in advance

Anil

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) Give us a problem we can solve. Show us your attempts, your sample data, your expected results. Give us something to work with.

Comment: Hi @larnu,this is not data related questions.its an approach related question?i have tried creating the ssis packages based on BIML language  which is xml an based.and I unaware of generating the input and output columns dynamically for script transformation..i just need a approach how to generate the same.below is the sample used https://varigence.com/Documentation/Samples/Biml/Script+Component+Project .i am just waiting for the approach  but not waiting for some one code to copy.

Comment: Then this doesn't have enough focus for us to help you with. SO is for programming related questions, and you do not appear to have a programming question here, and what you do ask isn't specific enough for us to provide more that opinions or a discussion; both of which are off topic.

Comment: Good article by Joost. The problem you have is that you want to dynamically generate the Column's collection for your input/output buffer. The answer will be based on how you define your metadata. The depth (1000 files) does not matter so much as the breadth (distinct file formats). I think your question would be answerable if you can provide us with how you're working with your metadata and how you expect to use it to define the buffers

Comment: Asked another way, do we assume you have a table-like object that describes the file formats or is the crux of the problem how can I inspect a file to determine what the proper file format is which then allows me to define my input/output buffers and their types

Comment: Hi Billnkc, Thanks for the quick reply, 
yes those are plain csv files(table formats) and all the text columns are encoded? 
we have a special logic to parse the same in the script component in DFT(which is row by row).
sample data is posted after decrypted. All those text related have to be part of the script component.
 Id,age,Name,Desc,smoke,n,y,ns
 1,40,Chintu, No descirpition,0,18790,2,0 
 2,50,Chow, No descirpition,0,10673,12,0 
 Here is the types
 Id--int,
age ->INT,
Name char(100),
Desc char(1000),
smoke bool,
n int,
y int,
ns int

Comment: I have finally achieved it and now i could able to create the columns dynamically in the script component. will share the piece of code once Tested. anyways thanks so much for your reply.

Comment: user2261767, I would recommend you share your solution as the answer. You can answer your own questions. Just a thought. Thanks.

Comment: @user2261767  Did your solution work after testing?  If so, are you able to post it as an answer?